# Generating Multiple Object Files from one Source File

Tags: gcc, linker, elf, conditional-compilation

**Question**

Is it possible to create multiple objects from a single source file, ideally by ELF section?  I know this is doable via external tooling after the fact via `elfutils` and friends but, unfortunately, I am stuck in a managed build environment and introducing new tooling mid-build is prohibitively complex (for now, at least).

**Additional Information**

This is ultimately for some dynamic symbol manipulation similar to U-Boot's command registration or Linux's initcall mechanism.  To assist with this, I have created the usual `__attribute__((used,section=""))` macro to generate these symbols in a known section.  Unfortunately, the managed build environment forces an intermediate static library which causes my generated symbols to be dropped as they are unreferenced in the main binary.

I know about `-Wl,-whole-archive` but I would prefer not to have to run this on my whole archive as this is an embedded project and space is at a premium.  Thus, I am hoping I can break out all of the dynamic symbols form the known section and conglomerate them into a single object which will form its own archive which can then be included completely without space penalty.

I also know about `--undefined` but I don't know the specific symbol names ahead of time so I don't see how this would work without a ton of brittle extra parsing.  Additionally, I am stuck on a SoC-provided toolchain of GCC 8.4.0 which doesn't support any kind of globbing [like LLVM does](https://reviews.llvm.org/D63244).

Comment: "It is fairly common to take multiple source files and produce a single object file" -- no, it's _not_.  The command you show certainly doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to go the other way and create multiple objects from a single source file

That is *very* common (but not in a single compiler invocation):

```
// x.c
#ifndef FOO
#define FOO Foo
#endif
int FOO() { return 42; }
```

```
gcc -c x.c -o foo.o
gcc -c x.c -DFOO=Bar -o bar.o
gcc -c x.c -DFOO=Baz -o baz.o
```

If you meant "multiple object files in a single compiler invocation", then no -- I know of no compiler that would do that.